# Configuring Magento 2.2.7 document root to pub

Tags: server-setup, index.php, magento2.2.7

In relation to this earlier question at [Difference between root index.php and pub directory index.php in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/243015/75686)

I'm using a cPanel hosted domain and am wondering if I should just set the document root as `~/Magento_Folder/pub` in the settings. Will it break anything or do I need access to the `httpd.conf` files which I can't get to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento root is folder in which you will find app, bin, dev, lib folder. So point out there not in pub.

Comment: there is another response that answers to you query at [is pub folder better to use for web hosting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/what-is-the-benefit-of-a-pub-directory-in-magento-2)